# Is there a way to manually update the tracking tables to jumpstart a sync?

Tags: c#, sql-server, microsoft-sync-framework

I am using the Microsoft Sync Framework "collaboration" providers. Both ends of the sync will use SQL Express to begin with. When provisioned the database contains a "_tracking" table for each "real" table in the database. My database is fairly large, and I don't want to transfer the entire thing via MSF on the first sync. Is there a way to use some other method to "jumpstart" the sync when both sides are known to contain the same data? In my testing when both databases contain identical content, it looks like it downloads the entire scope, churns through the entire batch of "changes", and then uploads the entire scope back to the server which then churns through the entire dataset again. Is there any way to update the _tracking tables (hopefully only on one side) to let the system know that the database contents are the same?

More information (**edit**):

From examining the contents of the tracking tables after doing an initial sync, it looks like the `scope_update_peer_timestamp` and `local_create_peer_timestamp` fields in every _tracking table need to be updated on both sides. In addition, the `update_scope_local_id`, `scope_update_peer_key`, and `last_change_datetime` need to be set on one of the two sides.

The `last_change_datetime` field is a datetime and is fairly self-explanatory.
The two `_timestamp` fields seem to use `@@DBTS` and are thus bigints that contain the equivalent of an editable timestamp column.

That still leaves a bunch of unknowns:

- Does MSF track which peer the content of the timestamp columns come from?
- Which peer (local or remote) drives the contents of the _timestamp fields?
- What logic drives the contents of the `update_scope_local_id` and `scope_update_peer_key` fields?

More information on the environment (**edit**):

I have SQL Express/Std on both sides. The server side will eventually contain information for several clients (using multi-tenancy), so backups will not be useful since the server will contain information for multiple clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how are you initializing your databases? are you provisioning databases that both contain the same set of data already?

the best way to initialize other replicas is to use the GenerateSnapshot method on the SqlCeSyncProvider that creates an SDF file to initialize other replicas or to do a back up of the database (non-SDF, SQL Server/Express database), restore it and run PerformPostRestoreFixup before doing a sync.

Comment: I added some more information about the environment. I'll take a look at `PerformPostRestoreFixup`, that may get me by for a little while.

Comment: so, your server already contains the same data from the clients? updating the _tracking tables wont help you. the _tracking tables simply records what has changed, not what has been synched. the information on what was synched or what is referred to as knowledge is in the scope_info table. if your databases contain data already by the time you provision, neither replica knows that their respective rows are the same until the first sync when they record what has been synched.